# configure a tableview to switch between two array as datasouce with RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I am new to RxSwift and have been trying to use tableview with RxSwift. 
I have a switch that toggles between two dataSources and according to it, respective tableviewcells are displayed.

Could anyone help me find what i might be doing wrong?

```
     func segmentControlledTableView() {
      typeRx.asObservable()
        .subscribe(onNext: { (type) in
            switch type {
            case RatesControllerType.location:
                self.branchList.asObservable()
                    .bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items) {
                        (tableView: UITableView, index: Int, element: 
                         BranchNearList) in
                        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 
                          0)
                        let cell = 
                         tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
                          "BranchesNearCell", for: indexPath) as! 
                           BranchesNearCell
                        cell.loadCell(element)
                        return cell
                    }
                    .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
                break
            case RatesControllerType.currency:
                self.currencyList.asObservable()
                    .bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items) {
                        (tableView: UITableView, index: Int, element: 
                          CurrencyNearList) in
                        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 
                          0)
                        let cell = 
                     tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
                      "CurrencyNearCell", for: indexPath) as! 
                      CurrencyNearCell
                        cell.loadCell(element)
                        return cell
                    }
                    .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
            }
        })
        .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

}
```

Comment: Whats the issue? what result you getting?

Comment: https://github.com/Iraniya/docTalk check this project In that insteed of searchBar add Observer to your toggle button, I think problem is with how you are initializing your cell?  why using withClass?

Comment: I'm sorry for that, that was a custom class i was using. I've corrected the above code now. And have fixed the issue as well. I've set the table's datasource and delegate to nil right before observing datasource. Thank you for your help :)